# How can I count a specific session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I want to know if i can count a specific session variable. 
I want to make a count of how many users are currenty logged in to the site and how many users are visiting the site right now.
Here is what i did (code)

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] + 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}

public void Session_OnEnd()
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] - 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

This code works fine, But now I got no idea how to count users that are logged in. I want to do something like that:

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
if (Session["IsLoggedIn"] == "true") 
{
Application.Lock();
Application["UsersLoggedIn"] = (int)Application["UsersLoggedIn"] + 1;
Application.UnLock();
    }
}
```

and then if the session is closed it will subtract 1 from the Application["UsersLoggedIn"]. My problem is that I cant count the 'IsLoggedIn' session on session start, because it is null and hence it wont work. So now we get to my quistion, Is there anyway to trigger the count of that application variable? Like to create an event when that session is true and then tell the application to add +1 to the counter on that event? Im sorry if my quistion wasnt clear, Please ask me for more deatils if its not clear and you just had no idea what i want from you. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Dirty, hacky, inefficient, solution (assumes use of forms authentication):

```
public void Global_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(
        Context.User != null && 
        !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.User.Identity.Name) && 
        Context.Session != null && 
        Context.Session["IAMTRACKED"] == null
    )
    {
        Context.Session["IAMTRACKED"] = new object();
        Application.Lock();
        Application["UsersLoggedIn"] = Application["UsersLoggedIn"] + 1;
        Application.UnLock();
    }
}
```

At a high level, this works by, on every request, checking if the user is logged in and, if so, tags the user as logged in and increments the login.  This assumes users cannot log out (if they can, you can add a similar test for users who are logged out and tracked).

This is a horrible way to solve your problem, but it's a working proto-type which demonstrates that your problem is solvable.

Note that this understates logins substantially after an application recycle; logins are much longer term than sessions.

Comment: It looks like it would work, but what do you mean that they cant logout? if the session is closed and it containted a "IsLoggedIn" == "true" value i want it to subtract 1 from the "UsersLoggedIn" application.

Comment: My point is that if a user logs out via a "log out" button on your site, that will not end the user's session, so you'll be counting them as still being logged in.

Comment: I think i can solve that by adding a code that if someone presses the logout button it will subtrac 1 from the application "usersloggedin", right?

Comment: I added the code that you showed here to global.asax and its not working, it does not shows the number of users logged in. (And yes, i changed the "IAMTRACKED" into my session variable )

Comment: I'm unsure what "its not working" means.  My first guess is that you did not hook `Global_BeginRequest` to `Application.BeginRequest`.  Also, you shouldn't need to change "IAMTRACKED" in order for this code to work (though changing it isn't a bad idea).  If you do change it, do not change it to an existing session variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the session items are client sided.
You can create a query to count the open connections (hence you're working with a MySQL database.)
Another option is to use external software (I use the tawk.to helpchat, which shows the amount of users visiting a page in realtime).
You could maybe use that, making the supportchat invisible, and only putting it on paging which are accesible for loggedin users.

OR

Execute an update query which adds/substracts from a column in your database (using the onStart and OnEnd hooks).

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem that you cannot do it using *Session[]* variables. You need to be using a database (or a central data source to store the total number of active users). For example, you can see in your application, when the application starts there is no `Application["UsersOnline"]` variable, you create it at the very instance. That is why, each time the application is started, the variable is initialized with a *new value*; always *1*.

You can create a separate table for your application, and inside it you can then create a column to contain *OnlineUsers* value. Which can be then incremented each time the app start event is triggered.

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] + 1;
    // At this position, execute an SQL command to update the value
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

Otherwise, for every user the session variable would have a new value, and you would not be able to accomplish this. Session variables were never designed for such purpose, you can access the variables, but you cannot rely on them for such a task. You can get more guidance about SQL commands in .NET framework, from MSDN's [SqlClient namespace library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Application["UsersOnline"]  is not a session variable, but application state so it should be possible to count that way, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, but why not something like this:

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
Application.Lock();

    if (Application["UsersOnline"] == null )
    {
       Application["UsersOnline"] = 0
     }


Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] + 1;
Application.UnLock();
```

}

Comment: That's the part the OP figured out.  The OP is asking how to count users who are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a reason you don't just want to use something like Google Analytics?

Unless you're looking for more queryable data, in which case I'd suggest what others have; store the login count to a data store. Just keep in mind you also have to have something to decrement that counter when the user either logs out or their session times out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application["cnt"] = 0;
    Application["onlineusers"] = 0;
    // Code that runs on application startup

}

 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["cnt"] = (int)Application["cnt"] + 1;

    if(Session["username"] != null)
    {
        Application["onlineusers"] = (int)Application["onlineusers"] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Application["onlineusers"] = (int)Application["onlineusers"] - 1;
    }

    Application.UnLock();
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
}
```

now you can display the number of users(Without Loggedin):

```
 <%=Application["cnt"].ToString()%>
```

and number of online users:

```
 <%=Application["onlineusers"].ToString()%>
```